# Modulus inside loop

Tags: php, loops, math, for-loop, modulus

I have an array that I am looping through and breaking up into chunks of 50. However occasionally the number of items inside that array are more than what fits inside that chunk of 50 ex.:

```
$array = array(); // has 220 rows

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    $j[] = $i;

    if ($i % 50 == 1) {
        print_r($j); // do something here with the 50 rows
        $j = null;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this will not print anything after `201`. I know there is some algebraic math involved in solving this but I am drawing a blank. Its times like these where I really wish I had paid attention in math class back in high school.

Comment: What is your desire output or resultant array ?

Comment: I think it's because it stops when count is 50. So after 200 it can't reach any more 50 rows, so it stops on 201.

Comment: never put the count, inside the for() you run the function n times instead of once

Comment: Basically I want to perform a batch request to the Facebook Graph API and it only takes a maximum of 50 at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) fits up your requirement and no maths required.

```
$result_array = array_chunk($array, 50, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add additional condition

```
if ($i % 50 == 1 || count($array)-1 == $i)
```

Comment: How would this work? By my logic `count($j)` will only ever reach a maximum of 50.

Comment: You're friggin kidding me. How did I not think of this!

Comment: but you should use @Rikesh answer.

Comment: @MeisamMulla, glad for you that you decided to use best practice

Answer (score 0):

You just have to redeclare the array is my guess:

```
$array = array(); // has 220 rows

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    $j[] = $i;

    if ($i % 50 == 1) {
        print_r($j); // do something here with the 50 rows
        $j = array() ;
    }
}
```

Once you perform `$j = null` there is no way you can do `$j[] = $i`

Comment: This isn't the issue. I get another array as expected when using `$j = null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(); // has 220 rows

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $j[] = $i;

    if ($i % 50 == 1) {
        doSomething($j); // do something here with the 50 rows
        $j = array(); // reset the array
    }
}
doSomething($j); // with the last 20 entries
```

After your loop is finished, you will have the remaining 201 through 220 entries in `$j`, so just do your stuff again.

Answer (score 0):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
 might be useful. Basically splits the array into chunks returning a multi dimensional array